# List arrangements in python from loops

Tags: python

My code is like this:

```
j=0
list1=[]

for port in portlist1:
    l=[[port.getname(),port.getsize()]]
    for register in port.getregisters():
        j=j+1
    l.append(j)
    list1.append(l)
    j=0
```

Output print list1 is:

```
      [[['B', 10], 2], [['C', 25], 1], [['F', 30], 0]]
```

what changes I should do if I want to use functions

```
      register.getaddress(),register.getdirection() inside 2nd for loop instead of increment j.
```

So my output should be:

```
 print list1:      [[['B', 10], [['1000',IN],['1',OUT]]], [['C', 25], ['v', 1001]], [['F', 30], []]]
 print list1[0]:   [['B', 10], [['1000',IN],['1',OUT]]
 print list1[0][1]:  ['1000',IN],['1',OUT]
```

Comment: What are `register.getaddress()` and `register.getdirection()`?

What are you wanting them to do?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. Instead of nested lists try using dictionary. Also python doesn't encourage declaring iteration count(`j`). Use `enumerate` instead.

Comment: @JamesPolley: register.get address() and register.getdirctions() gives me ['1000',IN]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this with a list comprehension:

```
list1 = []

for port in portlist1:
    l = [[port.getname(),port.getsize()],
         [[register.getaddress(), register.getdirection()]
          for register in port.getregisters()]]
    list1.append(l)
```

However, that gives you a nightmarishly deep nested list. I think that Babu's comment about using a dictionary was right on. Here's how you might improve things that way:

```
dict1 = {}
for port in portlist1:
    dict1[port.getname()] = {"size": port.getsize(),
                             "registers": {register.getaddress(): register.getdirection()
                                           for register in port.getregisters}}
```